# Writing to binary file as int in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where the output size is very important. As my outputs are numbers between 0 and 100, I'm trying to write them as bytes (or unsigned chars).

However, I'm getting errors when trying to read them.

Here is a simple example:

```
test_filename='test.b'
g=(3*ones(shape=[1000])).astype('c')
g.tofile(test_filename)

with open(test_filename, "rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read(1)
num = int(bytes.encode('hex'), 1)
print num
```

Here is the error I get, somehow the bytes.encode thingy excepts a binary string or something of that sort (not sure of course):

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-310a447041fe> in <module>()
----> 1 num = int(bytes.encode('hex'), 1)
      2 print num

ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36
```

I should state that I would later need to read the output files in C++.

Thanks in advance,

Gil

Comment: WHat are you trying to do here: `int(bytes.encode('hex'), 1)` ?

Comment: Looks like you want to read 1 byte. Instead you are casting to int with base `1`

Comment: Removed C++ tag since this is a Python question and C++ is only referenced.

Answer (score 0):

There is some iffiness to this based on the version of python you are using.

If python2, which I assume you are using because of the print statement, the main problem you have is that you are getting a string from the read, so if the value is say 50 you would get an ascii value of 2 if you print it.  You need to tell python that those bits should be in an int type not a str type and a simple cast does not do that.

I personally would use the struct package and do the following:

```
with open(test_filename, "rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read(1)
num = struct.unpack("B", bytes)[0]
print num
```

Another option would be to encode the string to hex and read it in as a hex string (which looks like is what you are trying):

```
num = int(bytes.encode("hex_codec"), 16))
print num
```

One final option would be to put the string in a bytearray and pull the first byte:

```
num = bytearray(bytes)[0]
print num
```

If you are actually using python 3 this is simpler because you will get back a bytes object (if so dont name a variable bytes, very confusing).  With a bytes object you can just pull the first element out which will be pulled out as an int:

```
num = bytes[0]
print num
```